# Cookie Dough Made From Pie Crust

Tags: cookies

Can I use Pillsbury premade pie crust for cookie dough?  If so, does it need to be flatten and add a little sugar?  Want to make some fruit filled cookies without making cookie dough.  Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

1. If you're located in a place where premade pie crusts are available, then you're located in a place where premade cookie dough should also be available.
2. Pie crusts contain no sugar, no eggs, no leavening, no flavoring. Adding any of these things after the fact is likely to result in a tough, uneven mess of a cookie. I wouldn't suggest it.
3. If you already have the pie crusts and need to use them up (for something other than pie), you can try rolling out the crusts pretty thin, cutting them into wedges, frying them, and immediately after they come out the oil, rolling them in powdered sugar. Serve with a nice fruit jam.

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice.  Merry Christmas.....

Answer (score 5):

A premade pie crust makes a yummy cookie base, and can be as simple as rolling it out and sprinkling it with sugar. That's pretty much how my favorite pie dough cookies, called [Cinnamon Sugar Buttons](http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/cinnamon-sugar-buttons.html), are made. For a more interesting cookie, you can mix things like cinnamon, nutmeg, ginger, pie spice, or other flavorings together with the sugar first.

I don't know what type of fruit cookie you're making, but you might want to keep the dough rather plain so it doesn't detract from the fruit. It can work the other way, though. For instance, if you're using an apple fruit mix, some cinnamon sprinkled on the cookie part can complement that.

It's important to remember that pie dough rises, and also flakes, so your cookies won't have the flat texture a normal cookie dough produces. The delicate layers can actually add a nice dimension to the recipe, though, so it's worth trying.

Let us know what happens!

Comment: Thank you very much for your advice.  Merry Christmas....

Comment: My pleasure! Merry Christmas back!